# Is there a way to create pptx download button using anchor tag in docusaurus?

Tags: babeljs, loader, docusaurus

Currently, I am writing MDX to create a dynamic download link to download the ppt file based on a condition.
When I use  , it is working fine but when I use the anchor tag I am unable to do it.
I get
[image: error]

I am trying to create a dynamic download link in docusaurus to download pptx file using the anchor tag as

<a target="_blank" href={require('path_to_file').default}> Download this docx